# Is it possible to select multiple tables with different quantity attributes?

Tags: mysql, sql

Note: I looked in this forum and could not find the solution I'm looking for.

These are the tables I created:

library:

```
name, registry
```

book:

```
date, author, code
```

Question 1: Is it possible to select the attributes of the two tables even though they have different attribute amounts?

Question 2: Can I access (select) the attributes of the `book` table through the `library` table?

Comment: what is the commonality between that tables ? presume all books are in the library

Comment: The `registry` is primary key. The `code` of the `book` is a foreign key. In this case, I would like to access the `author` of the `book` through the `library` table. The code I posted is just an example. You can add or remove attributes.

Comment: I suggest sitting down with any decent introductory book or tutorial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Q1: Yes, as long as they have a common relation (primary key, foreign key). If they have a relation you can always query to get items even if they have different number.

Q2: Yup! You can select books through the use of the library table. You can use something similar to:

```
SELECT book.author
FROM library
INNER JOIN book ON library.registry=book.code;
```